# Remove objects if they are duplicated with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, lodash

I'm trying to remove duplicated objects if the ids are the same with `lodash` `_.uniqBy`.

Or this doesn't have to be a `lodash` or `_.uniqBy`, but is this possible?

Also the id value is always dynamic,  so this time I want to remove the object with `id:123`, but other time it will be different `id`

```
import _ from "lodash";

export default function App() {
  const samples = [
    { id: 123, name: "Dan", age: 10 },
    { id: 234, name: "Jake", age: 22 },
    { id: 123, name: "Jake", age: 9 }
  ];

  let uniq = _.uniqBy(samples, samples.name);

  console.log(uniq);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {uniq.map((u) => (
        <p>{u.id}</p>
      ))}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or you can take a look at sample code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-matsumoto-eh4mvh?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I don't see any dupes in the above example. So you're expecting if `id: 2` has got `Dan` as the name, it needs to be filtered out?

Comment: It's just `_.uniqBy(samples, 'name');` or `'id'` if you want unique ids.

Comment: `samples.name` doesn't make sense. It's `"name"`.

Comment: `samples.name` isn't a thing; use `uniqBy` w/ property shorthand. This is [in the Lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy). `samples.name` refers to a property named `name` on `samples` but `samples` is an array and has no property `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide the property name which is `name` in your case. See [`_.uniqBy()` docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy).

```js
const samples = [{
    id: 123,
    name: "Dan",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    name: "Jake",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    name: "Jake",
    age: 9
  }
];

const unique = _.uniqBy(samples, 'name');
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

### Edit

As the question was edited: If you want to have it unique for `id` you should pass `"id"` instead of `"name"`.